# MbUnit Assert.AreEqual DateTime and Decimal are not equals

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mbunit

I have a class structure like this

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; 
}
```

I fill all the properties and save it to the DB, after that I get this object from the DB

```
var entity = CreateEntity()
SaveToDB(entity);
var entityFromDb = GetFromDB();
```

and try to compare the values in this way

```
Assert.AreEqual(entity, entityFromDb);
```

and the comparison is faild on the DateTime and Decimal values

Expected values to be equal.

Expected Value : 
Id = 28,
CreatedAt = 2011-01-05T14:06:32.**6874218Z**, 
DeletedAt = null, 
Description = "Description",
Duration = **2000m**, 
Label = "Test Entity",
ModifiedAt = 2011-01-05T14:06:32.**6874218Z**

Actual Value   : 
Id = 28,
CreatedAt = 2011-01-05T14:06:32.**0000000**, 
DeletedAt = null, 
Description = "Description",
Duration = **2000.00000m**,
Label = "Test Entity", 
ModifiedAt = 2011-01-05T14:06:32.**0000000**

Can I compare this values in some way, but without make a comparison of each fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to change your setters for DateTimes so that they perform the truncation at that point - basically the problem is that your DB isn't storing subsecond precision, so it seems reasonable not to have it in the entity either.

I'd expect the decimal values to be compared as equal already, even though they have different stored precision. (1.000m and 1.0m have different representations, but are deemed equal.)